# React Native expo-image-picker does not working all phone

Tags: react-native, axios, expo

I am using expo-image-picker and if I select an image in android emulator and save it, I cannot see the image I saved from emulator when I enter the program with my real device. In other words, with whichever device I save the picture, it only appears on that device. It does not appear on other devices. How can I solve this?

I am using API for database operations (with axios)

**Here is the code**

```
const PickImage = async () => {
allowPhotoRequests()

let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
  mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
  allowsEditing: true,
  aspect: [4, 3],
  quality: 1,
  base64: true
})

if (!result.cancelled) {
   setImage(result.uri) // I think I have to do something here
}
```

**Submit code:**

```
 const addPet = async () => {
try {
  petApi.post('/', {
    userId: userId,
    Age: age,
    Weight: weight,
    userName: currentUser,
    userPhone: currentUserPhone,
    petImage: image,
    city: city,
    district: district
  })
    .then(function (response) {
      alert('Success!')
    })
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

}

**Example image output:**

```
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/cache/ExperienceData/%2540yas1nkiziltas%252FPettyApp/ImagePicker/cb2923b3-5de8-4692-8244-0ce9b987001a.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can solve this problem as you're using this Expo:

1. Submit image data as `base64`
2. Review that backend API support `BLOB` and you can fetch `BLOB` with code
   below.

```
 const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function (e) {
      reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
    };
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.open("GET", [YOUR_FILE_PATH_URI], true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

// Use blob after fetch
console.log(blob)

// We're done with the blob, close and release it
blob.close();
```

Comment: Where exactly will I use the piece of code written with the blob? I would be very grateful if you could reply with the codes I gave above. @BYIRINGIRO Emmanuel

Comment: Most cloud objects storage providers ( AWS S3, Firebase Storage,... )  accept file upload as`blob`  and you can specify file extension any type of image (jpg,mp4, or pdf).
In case you're not using those storage providers, you should simply go with `base64`

Comment: I do 'base64:true' in the imagepicker as I mentioned in the code above, but the result is the same. other than that is there any other way to do it with base64?

Comment: The same you access `result.uri`, you can access  `result.base64`

`if (!result.cancelled) {

console.log(result.base64)
   setImage(result.uri) // I think I have to do something here
}`

Comment: I can see the translated data when I do console.log(result.base64) yes but I can't see it when trying to see the image as <Image source={{{uri: result.base64}} />. what is the problem?

Comment: Thank u so much !! to see the image I used set Image(result.uri) and this way to save it in database
setRealImage('data:image/jpg;base64,' + result.base64) really thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the petImage in your patApi database for a specific userId. On any device, to get that image, you need to fetch this data again, I don't see you fetching this image data back after you post it. This is the part you are missing.

Comment: I did<TouchableOpacity
              onPress={PickImage}
              style={styles.photos}>
              {
                image ? (
                  <Image
                    source={{ uri: image }}
                    style={styles.photoContent} />
                ) : (
                  <AntDesign
                    name="plus"
                    size={40}
                    color="gray"
                    style={styles.photoPlace}
                  />
                )
              }
            </TouchableOpacity>